# Create new column in pandas dataframe based on whether a value in the row reappears in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv I've imported as a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
TripId,  DeviceId, StartDate,                EndDate
817d0e7, dbf69e23, 2015-04-18T13:54:27.000Z, 2015-04-18T14:59:06.000Z
817d0f5, fkri449g, 2015-04-18T13:59:21.000Z, 2015-04-18T14:50:56.000Z
8145g5g, dbf69e23, 2015-04-18T15:12:26.000Z, 2015-04-18T16:21:04.000Z
4jhbfu4, fkigit95, 2015-04-18T14:23:40.000Z, 2015-04-18T14:59:38.000Z
8145g66, dbf69e23, 2015-04-20T11:20:24.000Z, 2015-04-20T16:22:41.000Z
...
```

I want to add a new column, with an indicator value based on whether the DeviceId reappears in my dataframe, with a StartDate 1hour after the current EndDate.
So my new dataframe should look like:

```
TripId,  DeviceId, StartDate,                EndDate,                  newcol
817d0e7, dbf69e23, 2015-04-18T13:54:27.000Z, 2015-04-18T14:59:06.000Z, 1
817d0f5, fkri449g, 2015-04-18T13:59:21.000Z, 2015-04-18T14:50:56.000Z, 0
8145g5g, dbf69e23, 2015-04-18T15:12:26.000Z, 2015-04-18T16:21:04.000Z, 0
4jhbfu4, fkigit95, 2015-04-18T14:23:40.000Z, 2015-04-18T14:59:38.000Z, 0
8145g66, dbf69e23, 2015-04-20T11:20:24.000Z, 2015-04-20T16:22:41.000Z, 0
...
```

I've started to write some code, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
df['newcol'] = np.where(df['DeviceId'].isin(df['DeviceId']) and , 1, 0)
```

One problem is that I'm not sure how to find device id in dataframe excluding current row, and another is that I don't know how to tackle the time issue.

EDIT: I've been working on it a bit, and my new code is now:

```
df['UniqueId'] = range(0, 14571, 1)

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

df2 = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['DeviceId'],keep=False)] 
#Returns list of trips with repeated deviceid
DeviceIds = df2['DeviceId'].tolist()
DeviceIds = list(set(DeviceIds))
for ID in DeviceIds:
    temp = df2.loc[df2['DeviceId'] == ID]
    temp.sort_values(by='StartDate')
    temp['PreviousEnd'] = temp['EndDate'].shift(periods=1)
    temp['Difference'] = temp['StartDate'] - temp['PreviousEnd']
    temp['Difference'] = [1 if x < pd.Timedelta('1H')
                      else 0 for x in temp['Difference']]
    temp = temp[['UniqueId','Difference']]
    df.join(temp, on='UniqueId', how='left',rsuffix='2')
```

The it creates the right temp dataframe, but I can't seem to join the values in Difference to the original dataframe

Comment: No problem, I try add comment to my answer. But if I dont know desired output I cannot check if my solution is what you want.

Comment: also maybe is necessary compare with `min` value, not `max`

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` and compare column `EndDate` with `max` value of `startDate` with `1H`:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    #not sure if 1 Hour as added to startDate and if is necessary compare
    #with ==, <, >
    return x.EndDate > (x.startDate + pd.Timedelta('1H')).max()

mask = df.groupby('DeviceId').apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reindex(df.index)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: EndDate, dtype: bool
```

Last convert `boolean mask` to `int`:

```
df['new_col'] = mask.astype(int)
print (df)
    TripId  DeviceId           startDate             EndDate  new_col
0  817d0e7  dbf69e23 2015-04-18 13:54:27 2015-04-18 14:59:06        0
1  817d0f5  fkri449g 2015-04-18 13:59:21 2015-04-18 14:50:56        0
2  8145g5g  dbf69e23 2015-04-18 15:12:26 2015-04-18 16:21:04        0
3  4jhbfu4  fkigit95 2015-04-18 14:23:40 2015-04-18 14:59:38        0
4  8145g66  dbf69e23 2015-04-20 11:20:24 2015-04-20 16:22:41        1
```

Comment: I've got a desired output in my question now. I'd like the new_col to be 1 if there exists in the dataframe a row with the same deviceId, and a start date at most 1 hour after the original rows end date.

Comment: Do you think your solution with `df['UniqueId']` ?

Comment: no, my solution is unfinished. I added uniqueId so once I've found which rows have a repeated deviceId I can map it back to my first dataframe

Comment: So my solution works well? I am a bit surprised, please check it.

Comment: no, it doesn't actually. I checked one of the deviceIds that only appears once and it has new_col value 1, despite there not being anything to compare it to.

Comment: I am not sure if I can help you, because I still dont understand what need. I know creating questions is not easy, but  I hope without your help I cannot find solution. Maybe is only necessary change your data for better sample where is more clear what need.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, the code I used was:

```
df['UniqueId'] = range(0, 14571, 1)

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
#converts dates to dateTime
df2 = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['DeviceId'],keep=False)] 
#Returns list of trips with repeated deviceid

DeviceIds = df2['DeviceId'].tolist()
DeviceIds = list(set(DeviceIds))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['UniqueId','Difference'])
for ID in DeviceIds: #creats mini dataframes for every DeviceId
    temp = df2.loc[df2['DeviceId'] == ID]
    temp.sort_values(by='StartDate')
    temp['PreviousEnd'] = temp['EndDate'].shift(periods=1)
    temp['Difference'] = temp['StartDate'] - temp['PreviousEnd']
    temp['Difference'] = [1 if x < pd.Timedelta('24H')
                      else 0 for x in temp['Difference']]
    temp = temp[['UniqueId','Difference']]
    df3 = pd.concat([df3,temp])
df.set_index('UniqueId').join(df3.set_index('UniqueId'),how='left')
```